# Is it 'Minor Edit Week' or something?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I've noticed that this week we're getting a lot of tiny pointless edits to posts (https://serverfault.com/users/100013/jakegould, https://serverfault.com/users/294235/lnux?tab=activity) - how are they getting approved and should we do something about it?

Comment: What could we do about it anyway? 2k users don't need a review for their edits, and others are motivated by the free rep points they get for changing `teh` to `the`...

Comment: It's *always* bowb the front page week...

Answer (score 1):

> Should we do something about these minor edits?

**Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged** and should be rejected when you encounter them in the review queue.

Although it is a good thing to edit and improve incorrect and outdated content the main disadvantage is that even a minor edit (on an older Q&A) bumps it to front page. So make your edits count on those posts.

On newly posted Q&A's; if you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so, please edit!

---

> How are they getting approved?

It only takes a minimal amount of rep before a user is allowed to propose edits to Q&A's, but those are **not** applied automatically. They enter a review queue where they need to be approved by 2 *established users* (= [rep > 2000](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/edit)) or a moderator.  Those same users can see the audit trail and the review history here: https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/history
Maybe the original author of the question/answer can also allow edits outside of the review queue, I'm not sure.

Established users (= [rep > 2000](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/edit)) get the privilege to have their edits applied immediately, without peer review.

> The user you linked to: https://serverfault.com/users/100013/jakegould?tab=activity

Is one such established users (= [rep > 2000](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/edit)) who has achieved both the privilege to have their edits applied immediately, without peer review and the privilege to participate in the edit review queue.

> The edit you linked to here: https://serverfault.com/users/294235/lnux?tab=activity

Was by a low-rep user and got approved from the [review queue here](https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/283315) by a fellow moderator.

---

Comment: A checkbox "minor edit only, do not bump to front page" would be helpful. It would encourage to correct spelling and punctuation errors, but not not pollute the front page with 2 year old questions that are already answered (where you have to hunt for the new timestamp).